# Feature test never update view with ajax response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, poltergeist

I have the following feature that I would like to test: post a comment and update my timeline with it. This is done asynchronously.

This is my form (partial):

```
<%= form_for [answer, comment], remote: true do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.text_area :content, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit btn_text, class: "btn btn-primary pull-right" %>
<% end %>
```

This is my action:

```
  def create
    @answer = Answer.find(params[:answer_id])
    @comment = @answer.comments.create(comment_params.merge(user: current_user))

    respond_to { |format| format.js }
  end
```

This is rendered as answer of my action:

```
<% if @comment.errors.any? %>
  $('#new_comment').prepend('<%= escape_javascript(render "shared/error_messages", object: @comment) %>');
<% else %>
  // Add comment in the timeline.
  $(".timeline").prepend("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'comment', locals: { comment: @comment }) %>")
  $("#comment_content").val("");
<% end %>
```

And finally, this is my feature test (I'm using RSpec, Capybara and Poltergeist):

require 'rails_helper'

```
describe "Post a comment", js: true do
  let(:teacher) { create(:user, :teacher) }
  let!(:answer) { create(:answer) }

  before do
    login_as teacher
    visit answer_path(answer)
    fill_in "comment_content", with: "comment"
    click_on "Postar comentário"
  end

  it "add the comment to the page" do
    expect(page).to have_selector("li.time-label span", count: 1)
    expect(page).to have_selector("div.timeline-item", count: 1)
  end
end
```

This feature works fine in development environment, but not in this feature test. I receive the "not find error:

```
  1) Post a comment add the comment to the page
     Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_selector("li.time-label span", count: 1)
       expected to find css "li.time-label span" 1 time but there were no matches
```

I checked out with a printscreen, and the form submit button still pressed, as if waiting for an answer yet (I increased `Capybara.default_max_wait_time`, but the answer never comes).

However, checking in test logs, the `create.js` who add the comment to the page, is called:

```
Processing by CommentsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "comment"=>{"content"=>"comment"}, "commit"=>"Postar comentário", "answer_id"=>"1"}
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.3ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?[0m  [["id", 4], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[36mAnswer Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "answers".* FROM "answers" WHERE "answers"."id" = ? LIMIT ?[0m  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[36mbegin transaction[0m
  [1m[35mSQL (0.3ms)[0m  [1m[32mINSERT INTO "comments" ("answer_id", "user_id", "content", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)[0m  [["answer_id", 1], ["user_id", 4], ["content", "comment"], ["created_at", 2017-04-09 13:06:14 UTC], ["updated_at", 2017-04-09 13:06:14 UTC]]
  [1m[35m (316.9ms)[0m  [1m[36mcommit transaction[0m
  Rendering comments/create.js.erb
  Rendered shared/_error_messages.html.erb (0.9ms)
  Rendered comments/_form.html.erb (108.9ms)
  Rendered comments/_comment.html.erb (221.3ms)
  Rendered comments/create.js.erb (236.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 784ms (Views: 239.8ms | ActiveRecord: 317.7ms)
```

What can be happening here?

EDIT:

`comments/_comment.html.erb`:

```
<li id="comment-<%= comment.id %>">
  <i class="fa fa-envelope bg-blue"></i>

  <div class="timeline-item">
    <span class="time">
      <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
      <%= comment.created_at.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S") %>
    </span>

    <div class="timeline-body">
      <div id="comment-<%= comment.id %>-content">
        <%= comment.content %>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="pull-left" style="color: grey; margin-right: 20px" title="Hora de postagem">
      <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
      <%= comment.created_at.strftime("%H:%M:%S") %>
    </div>

    <% if comment.created_at != comment.updated_at %>
      <div class="pull-left" style="color: grey" title="Data e hora de alteração">
        <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>
        <%= comment.created_at.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S") %>
      </div>
    <% end %>

    <div class="pull-right">
      <%= link_to comment, method: :delete, remote: true, title: "Deletar comentário",
          data: { confirm: "Tem certeza que deseja excluir esse comentário?" } do %>
          <i class="fa fa-times" style="color: red; margin-right: 4px"></i>
      <% end %>

      <a id="edit-comment-<%= comment.id %>" href="#" target="">
        <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>
      </a>
    </div>

  </div>
</li>

<script>
  $('#edit-comment-<%= comment.id %>').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#comments-form').html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'comments/form', locals: { comment: comment, answer: nil, btn_text: 'Salvar' } ) %>");
    $('#comments-form').append("<a id='cancel-edit' href='#'>Cancelar edição</a>");
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Well Not found is clear. Try checking the html selector i.e. "li.time-label span" before and after the action. Sometimes there is just a minor human error.

Comment: I checked @Mayank. The selector is this, and it isn't there, causing the error. The point is: it should be there, because the `create.js` is rendered, as my log pointed out.

Comment: okay, please share code for comment partial if possible

Comment: Question updated with the partial code.

Comment: Just to inform: `li.time-label span` selector comes from `comments_timeline` partial.

Comment: Could it be a timing issue? Capybara should be waiting for the ajax call to finish but the example may be run before the content is added to the page. Try adding `sleep(1)` at the beginning of the example.

Comment: I tryed this and also increase`Capybara.default_max_wait_time`, @max. It doesn't worked.